# RiotJs How to do computed properties

Tags: javascript, riot.js

The parent makes some computation before passing down the attribute

```
<parent>
    <child src={compute(opts.src)}></child>
</parent>
```

It doesn't work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MguuodHHRlVytnikQKZ7?p=preview

How to achieve this?

It is very basic fixture in Web Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RiotJS converts the `src` property in the opts object to a property called `riotSrc` due to not allowing illegal server requests when using `src=""` on tags.

```
<child>
  <div>This is the original property: {opts.origin}</div>
  <div>This is the computed property: {opts.riotSrc}</div>
</child>
```